# Advanced git scenarios

Tags: git

I have several advanced scenarios I would like to solve, but I don't know how. I hope you can help:

1. `A - B - C - D - E`. I would like to add the changes from commit `D` into commit `B` and remove commit `D`. How?
2. `A - B - C`. Commit `B` contains a file that should not have been committed. How to remove it from the commit?
3. `A - B - C - D`. Commit `C` contains a file that should have been committed with commit `B`. How to remove it from commit `C` and add it to commit `B`?

Please note: All commits are in my working copy only and have not yet been pushed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answers use `git rebase` quite a lot. If you're new to rebasing, [be sure to read this chapter on git rebase first](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html)

1. <strike>`git cherry-pick B`</strike> Like you found out yourself, you could `rebase -i A` and swap the C/D revisions, squashing B+D together.
2. `git rebase -i B`, mark B as edit and apply changes.

   > Now to *really* remove the objects from the object database you may need to use filter-branch on all branches containing the object. After that, it may take a while for reflogs to expire. If the object is a security sensitive one, you may want to `git gc --aggressive --prune=tomorrow`. The [Pro Git book has a section on *removing objects*](http://progit.org/book/ch9-7.html#removing_objects). 
   > <sub><sup>With `git-filter-branch` always remember to include `--tag-name-filter cat`, see comments</sup></sub>
3. If all of C should be in B, simply

   `git rebase -i B` mark `C` with squash and it will squash the commits together.

   > If it gets any more involved than that (only a single file from C needs to go in B), I'd split the job into smaller steps that can be solved as in the above steps:
   >
   > - split commit C in two parts: one (C.1) to merge into commit B and one (C.2) to keep as the new 'C'. E.g. from the Git Pro chapter linked above:
   >
   > > <sub>If you wanted to split a commit, for instance, you would specify 'edit' for that commit:</sub>
   > >
   > > ```
   > > pick   fc62e55 added file_size
   > > pick   9824bf4 fixed little thing
   > > edit   21d80a5 added number to log
   > > pick   76b9da6 added the apply command
   > > pick   c264051 Revert "added file_size"
   > > ```
   > >
   > > And then when you get to the command line, you revert that commit and create two (or more) new ones. Lets say 21d80a5 modified two files, file1 and file2, and you wanted to split them into seperate commits. You could do this after the rebase dropped you to the command line :
   > >
   > > ```
   > > $ git reset HEAD^
   > > $ git add file1
   > > $ git commit 'first part of split commit'
   > > $ git add file2
   > > $ git commit 'second part of split commit'
   > > $ git rebase --continue
   > > ```
   > >
   > > And now instead of 5 commits, you would have 6.
4. rebase to merge commits B and C.1

Comment: Could you elaborate on "remember to include `--tag-name-filter cat`"? Why is it dangerous, and why should it always be included?

Comment: @unutbu: by default git filter branch 'rewrites' (filters) the revision tree reachable from the refnames listed on the command line (or HEAD). Using `--all` you can cause _almost_ all refnames to be rewritten). However, tagnames are not rewritten _unless_ the `--tag-name-filter` parameter is present. This could lead to nasty surprises when forgotten (suddenly the tags resolve to 'obsolete' commits, that have long since been rewritten). Now **in practice** tags are used mainly for **published** versions, and you shouldn't be rewriting **published history** anyway.

Comment: ... Still I'd have loved it if the `cat` tag name filter were the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive answer. I will read it and the provided links and check back afterwards.

Comment: @sehe: Thanks. 1) cherry pick didn't work, it created conflicts. However, I used `git rebase -i` and switched commits `C` and `D` and changed `pick` in front of `D` to `f`.

Comment: @sehe: Hm, the rebase on question 1 messed up my branches. My history was like this: `A - B- C - D - E - F`, with a second branch with commit `F*` starting from `E`. After the rebase, the branch starts no longer from `E` but from `A`. How would I do the rebase so it applies to all branches this commit is in?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: i'm so sorry, I appear to have misread the question no. 1., quite embarassingly so - I mean it wasn't like you phrased it unclearly. Sorry about that. Now `How would I do the rebase so it applies to all branches this commit is in`: two ways: you could rebase the 'dependent' branches back onto the rewritten base series (`A - (B+D') - C -E`) (_my vote goes here_). Alternatively, if the _literal commit sequence (`A - B - C - D -E`)_ (i.e. not merged, cherrypicked but the same commit _ids_) occurs in all branches, you could repeat the same rebase recipe with some hackery ...

Comment: ... (i.e. not using an editor to pick the commits). One final general remark: all rebases involving re-ordering or removal of commits have the potential to create merge conflicts.

Comment: @sehe: Thanks again for your answer. I will try that (after I understood it :-) ). About the merge conflicts: As far as I understand, this is only a problem when I already pushed those commits, correct?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: no, merge conflicts happen, e.g. when you want to reorder commits around that changed the same lines of code. The deltas won't apply cleanly. In fact, you'd rarely want to reorder such commits :) That is unrelated to the general caveat of rewriting git history after publishing it. (_The latter is what I referred to the Git book chapter for._)

Comment: A little follow up: I became a big fan of `git rebase` in the meantime! :-)